# Is possible to download markdowns from git directly to hugo?

Tags: hugo

I am new with hugo and I dont find the way to addresss it.

My idea is use hugo in docker and get the content from another source, this way hugo will be updated.
The source can be almost anything, but I would prefer a repository.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

From https://firepress.org/en/best-practices-for-getting-code-into-a-container/ it might be an option to use wget to download the data you want.

There might be better ways, but this one seemed like a pretty viable way to accomplish what you want.
I removed some "logging" features from the given sample and added some explanations of what does what.

```
##############################################################################
# Install App
##############################################################################

WORKDIR $APP

# Some of the APK's are installed that will be removed later in this process.
RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk --no-cache add tar curl tini \
    && apk --no-cache add --virtual devs gcc make python wget unzip ca-certificates \
    && apk del devs gcc make python wget unzip ca-certificates \
    && npm cache clean \
    && rm -rf /tmp/npm*


##############################################################################
# PART ONE
# Install/copy FirePress_Klimax into casper from Github
##############################################################################

#directory name, for url building and renaming the unpacked zip.
THEME_NAME_FROM="FirePress_Klimax"; \
# directory where the file should be
THEME_NAME_INTO="casper"; \

# The url where to get you data from.
GIT_URL="https://github.com/firepress-org/$THEME_NAME_FROM/archive/master.zip"; \

# Local directory names.
DIR_FROM="$DIR_THEMES/$THEME_NAME_FROM"; \
DIR_INTO="$DIR_THEMES/$THEME_NAME_INTO"; \

# enter the themes directory. 
cd $DIR_THEMES; \
# download the master.zip
wget --no-check-certificate -O master.zip $GIT_URL; \
# unzip the master.zip that was downloaded from github.
unzip $DIR_THEMES/master.zip; \   
# remove the zip file, since the contents are on disk now
rm $DIR_THEMES/master.zip; \
# rename the "master" directory that's on disk now to it's proper name
mv $THEME_NAME_FROM-master $THEME_NAME_INTO; \        

##############################################################################
# Clean up
##############################################################################
# delete the apk cache of unneeded cached downloads
rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*; \
# we don't need these programs anymore
apk del wget unzip ca-certificates;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hugo has inbuilt functionality for you [Modules](https://gohugo.io/hugo-modules/), The module can be used to fetch the files from git and also you can specify which folder from git repo needs to be placed on where at your Hugo

- List item

  site. This happens at the time of Build.

You may need to install Go language to get this work.